# Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit unable to import using directive

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have downloaded and installed Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit and I am able to include it in the xaml page, but I am unable to include it in the C# file(like "using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" ). any idea why this happens?

Comment: When you say you are able to include it in the XAML page, what does that mean? Are the controls showing up on the page when you run in debug mode? Also, can you confirm that you added the toolkit to your project's References?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...try to build and after add

`using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit;`

Comment: i pressed f6 for building the project, after it is built successfully, i tried including "using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit. but still it doesn't get recognized

Answer (score 1):

For the xaml:

***xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"***

You can use the controls in the C# file after you add the code post above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the DLL as a reference to the project?